Is it possible for the Human Task User to change the SLA, if the given task isn't completed within the Due Date
The requirement is that, within the given SLA, if the User isn't able to complete the task, idly the control goes the next node, by simply ending the Human Task.
But in this case, is it possible for the user to Update the SLA, even after the given Due Date has reached.
NOTE: Kogito 0.1.3
Is it possible for the Human Task User to update the already assigned SLA to a Due Date?
